# How to call screenshot method from one class to other class?How to take screenshot of home page after navigating in to my code?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

How to call screenshot method from one class to other class?
How to take screenshot home page after logging in to my code?

Below are the classes:-

Properties class:

```
package basepackage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler;

public class PropertiesClass extends BaseClass {

    public static String propfile(String username) throws IOException {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\pushk\\eclipse-workspace\\com.org.swag\\config.prop");
        prop.load(fis);
        return prop.getProperty(username);

    }

    public static void loginscreenshot() throws Exception {
        File file = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileHandler.copy(file, new File("C:\\Users\\pushk\\eclipse-workspace\\com.org.swag\\Screenshots.png"));

    }
```

LoginPageClass:

```
package com.org.swag.Page;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import com.org.swag.pageobject.LoginPageObjects;
import basepackage.BaseClass;
import basepackage.PropertiesClass;

public class LoginPage extends BaseClass {
    public void loginpage() throws Exception {
        LoginPageObjects lpo = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageObjects.class);
        lpo.username.sendKeys(PropertiesClass.propfile("username"));
        lpo.password.sendKeys(PropertiesClass.propfile("password"));
        lpo.loginsubmit.click();
        lpo.menu.click();
        lpo.logout.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your code to a readable format.

Comment: done editing.have a look now

Comment: You need to pass webdriver reference to the screenshot method.
Change your loginscreenshot() method to accept Webdriver as a parameter and then you can call it from your main class (Login Class)

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the `static` screenshot method from another class (which imports `basepackage.PropertiesClass`) at the desired step. In your code, add the call after logging in:

```
    LoginPageObjects lpo = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageObjects.class);
    lpo.username.sendKeys(PropertiesClass.propfile("username"));
    lpo.password.sendKeys(PropertiesClass.propfile("password"));
    lpo.loginsubmit.click();

    PropertiesClass.loginscreenshot();

    lpo.menu.click();
    lpo.logout.click();
```